# How to get PURE fire in Quick Smoke preoperties

Tags: smoke-simulation, fire

another question here for today.

Im playing around with fire and smoke simulations, and I was experimenting with "Fire & Smoke", and i get, as expected, fire with smoke. But when i go with "Fire", it also gives me Fire with smoke. I just want Pure fire without any smoke, and i think it may have something to do with Nodes. Thanks, if anyone has any ideas.

Thanks.

Comment: Just give the density of smoke a value of zero.

Comment: please write an answer to your own question. Others might find it useful.